# Node.js & Handlebars: Rendering array in page

Tags: arrays, node.js, handlebars.js

I've been fighting through this issue, which I'm sure has a simple answer, for long enough to ask for help.  I'm trying to output the contents of an array (famlist) to a web page in a Node.js/handlebars webapp. I'm pretty sure my issue revolves around passing the array to the render.get statement inside the index.hbs.  The console.log for familylist does work correctly. I've removed all my failed attempts and have it listed below as it works without the array working.  I'm looking for what I need to add... Thanks in advance for any help!

Here my code:

**Handlebars View Page:**

```
<p> Currently entered list:
    <ul class="people_list">
      {{#each famArray}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
</p>

{{#if errors}}
    {{#each errors}}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{this.msg}}
    </div>
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

**Index.hbs section:**

```
router.get('/profile', authenticationMiddleware(), function(req, res) {
const db = require('../db.js');
db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " + req.user.user_id, function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    username = results[0].username;
    db.query(`SELECT familyname FROM family WHERE user = "${username}"`, function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        var famlist = results;
        console.log(famlist);
        res.render('profile', {
            famlist: famlist
        } {
            title: 'Profile'
        });

        function createHTML(results) {
            var rawtemplate = document.getElementById("famtemplate").innerHTML;
            var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(rawTemplate);
            var ourGeneratedHTML = compiledTemplate(results);

            var famContainer = document.getElementById("fam-container");
            famContainer.innerHTML = ourGeneratedHTML;
        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: I don't see where you're including `famlist` to your render.  Also, your `res.render` should be after your db query - where your `console.log` is.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I moved the render section to where you specified and put in the array call as I've seen it done.  It doesn't work though.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your render should be after your database call and in the following format:

```
res.render('profile', {
  famlist: famlist,
  title: 'Profile'
})
```

Comment: Thats better!  Now I'm getting the following on the page:  [object Object]
[object Object], once for each item.  Now the issue is with my array I think.  The console log of famlist is "RowDataPacket { familyname: 'Kristina' } .  Think I may need to trim that down.

Comment: try `{{this.familyname}}`

Comment: Using this "{{this.familyname}}" did it, thanks so much for the assistance and education!